# Preventing Click jacking using X-Frame-Options

Tags: javascript, http-headers, clickjacking

I am trying to prevent clickjacking for an application that does not use any iframes. On reading I understand that the X-Frame-Options should be set to deny. However, I am not sure how to go about doing it?

Should a Filter be created? Or is it done in a javscript? ] This application has several controllers? Would the controllers have to add the header to the response?

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` is an HTTP response header. You set it either in your web server configuration or server side code. There isn't enough information about your system in the question to suggest the best way for *you* to do it.

Comment: Apologize for not explaining clearly. I trying to understand how is the X-Frame-Options  options normally set?How can I do it via the server side code. Should a filter be created? How can it be done in the web server configuration?

Comment: "how is the X-Frame-Options options normally set" — Depends on the server side environment. "How can I do it via the server side code" — Depends on your server side environment. Python/CGI and Catalyst/Plak/GCI work differently. "Should a filter be created" — What's a filter? "How can it be done in the web server configuration" — What web server? Nginx and IIS work differently.

Comment: Sorry- I am not very educated on this topic. Hence, I am looking for some help. What I am trying to figure out is do people normally just update their web server config or do they update their server side code. the owasp site says"A possibly simpler way is to implement a filter that automatically adds the header to every page. " . I am assuming this is the javax.servlet.Filter interface, where you implement the doFilter. I was not able to find any concrete examples anywhere, which is why I turned here.

Comment: "do people normally just update their web server config or do they update their server side code" — Depends on their specific circumstances and personal preference.

Comment: "I am assuming this is the javax.servlet.Filter interface" — Maybe… but I don't know much about Java servlets and you didn't mention that you were using them in your question or tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) is an HTTP Header which is set on the HTTP response of documents (HTML or others).

Since it is set by the HTTP Server, it's implementation is highly dependent on the server architecture. It might be able to be set globally by content-type, or it might require specific settings for each file or route. It all depends on the situation.